# What is the gsutil equivalent to objects/get?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

There is a method on GCP's Cloud Storage API that enables the caller to retrieve object metadata. it is documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

Is there a `gsutil` equivalent to this method? I've tried `gsutil ls -L gs://object` however it returns more information than calling the API method does.

---

Background to my question is that I am implementing a custom role to apply permissions on GCS buckets/objects. In order to test that custom role I am writing a script that carries out all the operations that a member of that custom role will need to be able to do. One of the permissions that the role members will require is storage.objects.get and I basically want to know what `gsutil` command is enabled by granting someone storage.objects.get. According to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-json, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get does require storage.objects.get and hence why I'm trying to find the equivalent `gsutil` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to view the metadata associated with an object run:

```
gsutil stat gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
```

If you want to retrieve the object itself from the cloud and store it in a local path run:

```
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCATION]
```